# $\{(X,Y)\in \Bbb R^3: |X|=|Y|=1, \langle X,Y \rangle=0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\text{SO}(3, \Bbb R)$

Tags: lie-groups, orthogonality

> Let $R=\{(X,Y)\in \Bbb R^3: |X|=|Y|=1, \langle X,Y \rangle=0\}$ with $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ the Euclidean scalar product.
>
> Prove that $R$ is homeomorphic to $\text{SO}(3, \Bbb R)$.

I don't know where to start. My intuition is to build a map from $R$ to some  space $X$ in $\mathcal{F}(X,Y)$  , that preserves the scalar product which would mean that this space $X$ is $O(3)$. but I don't know how.

Thanks for your hints, comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Expand the defining equation $A^{\top} A = I$ in the usual definition $$SO(n, \Bbb R) := \{A : A^{\top} A = I, \det A = 1\}$$ in terms of the column vectors of $A$.

> Writing $A = \pmatrix{{\bf A}_1 & \cdots & {\bf A}_n}$, the condition becomes $\langle {\bf A}_i , {\bf A}_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$, $1 \leq i, j, \leq n$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol.

Comment: Thank you! So we might extend (X,Y) into a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ using the cross product as suggested by @Kenny Wong? or there is another subtlety?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the construction the answer hints at is essentially that in Kenny's: The condition on the ${\bf A}_i$ tells us that, for example, the first two columns ${\bf A}_1,{\bf A}_2$ of any $A\in SO(3,\Bbb R)$ satisfy the hypotheses on a pair $({\bf X},{\bf Y})$, suggesting a candidate homeomorphism $SO(3,\Bbb R) \to R$, namely, ${\bf A}\mapsto({\bf A}_1,{\bf A}_2)$. So, the inverse of such a map has the form $({\bf X},{\bf Y})\mapsto\pmatrix{{\bf X}&{\bf Y}&\ast}$, and we can show that the condition that the image is in $SO(3, \Bbb R)$ forces $\ast$ to be ${\bf X}\times{\bf Y}$.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition would be to show that there for any $\vec X, \vec Y \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $|\vec X  | = | \vec Y | = 1$ and $\vec X . \vec Y = 0$, there exists a unique $M \in \rm{SO}(3)$ that sends $(1,0,0) \mapsto \vec X$ and $(0,1,0) \mapsto \vec Y$.

(Indeed, such an $M$ must necessarily send $(0,0,1) \mapsto \vec X \times \vec Y$, where $\times$ denotes the vector cross product. This is because $M$, being special orthogonal, maps right-handed orthonormal bases to right-handed orthonormal bases, and $\vec X \times \vec Y$ is the only vector that extends $\{ \vec X, \vec Y \}$ to form a right-handed basis. Having specified how $M$ acts on the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$, $M$ is now fully determined.)

Comment: So the continuity of the inverse map that maps M to its first two columns  is obvious hence the homeomorphism, thank you!